# Difference between Object and Class

Tags: java

lets say we have this class without any constructors and instances variables

```
public class ConsoleWriter{
  public void write(){
    System.out.println("Console Writing...");
  }
}
```

and you have another class App with 2 variables console and console1

```
public class App{
   ConsoleWriter console;
   ConsoleWtiter console1=new ConsoleWriter();
}
```

Now I understand that console1 is an object of ConsoleWriter while console is just a reference type to ConsoleWriter.

When having such case (No constructors, No instance Variable)

what is the difference ?

or how would it be useful to create the Object `console1` if we could just do it using the `console`.

```
console.write();//would output Console Writing...
console1.write();//would output Console Writing...
```

Comment: console.write() would lead to nullpointer exception since it is not initilazed

Comment: There is nothing in this question about 'difference between Object and Class. Please fix your title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
console1 is an object of ConsoleWriter
```

Incorrect it is a reference that will point to Object of type ConsoleWriter. Since uninitialized it will point to `null`. Also you cannot call methods on this as it is uninitialized.

```
console.write();//would output Console Writing...
```

This is also incorrect. Must be initialized first.

```
ConsoleWtiter console1=new ConsoleWriter();
```

This is equivalent to

```
ConsoleWtiter console1;
```

which creates a reference which will point to Objects/instances of class ConsoleWriter. Since it is an instance variable it is assigned default value i.e null.

```
console1 = new ConsoleWriter();
```

At this point the reference console actually points to an Object of class ConsoleWriter. It is only after this(initialization) you can call methods of the class.

Comment: Ok thanks for this explanation but when would it be useful to use the ConsoleWriter alone without initializing it in which cases?

Comment: @user3135757 It wouldn't be useful to *never* initialise it, but seperating out the declaration and initialisation allows it to be initialised in different ways (in the simplest case think of an if statement with two different constructors being used), or in a completely seperate function (which then returns a `new ConsoleWriter()`)

Comment: It is just a pointer. There is nothing much you can do with it. Though you can use to get the return value of a function or as an argument in function. If you have some subclass then you can use it as polymorphic reference. But to summarize it is not useful unless it points to some actual object.

Answer (score 2):

"Now I understand that console1 is an object of ConsoleWriter while console is just a reference type to ConsoleWriter." - Wrong. Both console and console1 are references.. The difference is that console1 points to a ConsoleWriter object whereas console doesnt point to anything.

So. console.anyFunction() will give you an exception (NulPointerException) because console is not initialized whereas console1.someFunction() will work as console1 points to a ConsoleWriter Object.

Answer (score 1):

See the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> For all reference types [(§4.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3), the default value is null.

So when you write:

```
ConsoleWriter console;
console1.write();
```

It's like writing:

```
null.write();  //Will throw NullPointerException
```

On the other hand, when you do:

```
ConsoleWriter console1=new ConsoleWriter();
```

Then you are *constructing* a new *object* of type `ConsolWriter`.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to know the difference between *Declaring, Instantiating and Initializing an Object*

```
ConsoleWriter console;
ConsoleWiter console1=new ConsoleWriter();
```

No, the below lines are wrong

```
console.write();//would output Console Writing...
console1.write();//would output Console Writing...
```

You face a NullPointerException  in first line.

You have'nt to initialize it and now  it's holding default value `null`.

Where as second line  executes the `write()`  method. In order to use it further you have to initialize it.

Recomminding : [`Declaring, Instantiating and Initializing an Object`](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~daeron/docs/javaguide/java/anatomy/creating.html)

Answer (score 1):

`console.write();` will give you runtime exception most probably null pointer exception

But

```
 ConsoleWtiter console1=new ConsoleWriter();
console1.write();
```

would give you

```
Console Writing...
```

Answer (score 1):

`console` isn't usable. It's not a `ConsoleWriter`; it's null. If you try to call its methods, you'll get a NullPointerException. This isn't C++, where

```
ConsoleWriter console;
```

constructs a `ConsoleWriter`.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I understand that console1 is an object of ConsoleWriter

No. `console1` is a reference to `ConsoleWriter` which isn't null, because you initialized it.

> while console is just a reference type to ConsoleWriter.

Correct. `console1` is a reference to `ConsoleWriter` which is null, because you didn't initialize it.

> what is the difference ?

The difference is that you didn't initialise one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Any `class` without a constructor specified always has the default constructor you can use. In your case this is:

```
public class ConsoleWriter{
  public ConsoleWriter(){
  }
}
```

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question.